# regex - exclude last character from match

Tags: regex, gsub

How do I exclude the last character in my match when trying to include a comma between each nth charater?

input: `DFPR`

find: `(.{1})`

replace: `\1,`

current output: `D,F,P,R,`

desired output: `D,F,P,R`

example: https://regex101.com/r/liENfO/6

Comment: Try to search for `\B` and replace by `,`.

Comment: @oriberu doh! i knew that! too easy! Thanks.

Comment: Np. :) If you need to do this with more than just word characters, you could also use `(.)(?=.)` and replace with `\1,`. Not quite as elegant though. ^^

Comment: @oriberu for some reason `\B` did not work properly when vectorized but the `(.)(?=.)` did.

Comment: @oriberu this seems to be giving me issues when i apply it to my program. I'm using `r` and when do `gsub("(.)", "\\1,", c("FPR", "DFPR"))` it puts a comma after the last letter. However, when i do `gsub("(.)(?=.)", "\\1,", c("FPR", "DFPR"))` it gives me an error for an invalid `regex`. the `(?=.)` seems to work fine in the `regex` tester. Would you know anything about that?

Comment: Google tells me you'll need Perl mode to use lookaround assertions with R's regex functions; so, `gsub("(.)(?=.)", "\\1", c("FPR", "DFPR"), perl = TRUE)`? Can't test it.

Comment: That does it! Thank you. I was not aware of perl mode.